# Android Version Vs API levels

Tags: android, sdk

I am beginner in Android development and couldn't find the major difference between Android versions and API levels??I have tried from different sites but couldn't perceive.

Answer (score 0):

> Well, API is for development, so the changes in new API version are
>   more "inside". But new version of Android usually adds more features
>   for users, that are "visible".[Android: API level VS. Android version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629687/android-api-level-vs-android-version)

Check out this article: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels